# Basics 101 - what is the concept of creating a employee share pool and what happens to existing shares?

Tags: shares

- We have a startup with 3 initial share holders, sharing 10,000 shares divided 2500/3700 and 3800.
- We want to get things in order now for investment and pre-emptively create an option pool for employees.
- We currently envisage letting a % goto investment.

How exactly are shares split up when people "buy in" as it does not seem logical to recall existing certificates to issue new ones.

**Scenario:** An investor agrees to invest an amount of money in return for 10% of the company.

Assuming new shares are issued to award the investor 10% this makes it improbable that everyone is going to get exactly the share % they expect.

For example:

- Today there are 10000 shares
- To calculate the new qty of shares we assume 10000 is 90% so:  (10000/90)*100 = **11111.11**
- It is not possible to issue .11 of a share (at least in the UK)

So, what typically happens here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's up to you, your investor, and the agreement you come to.

Most likely, you and the investor would agree that

- The company will issue x new shares
- The investor will purchase those x new shares for y dollars

You and the investor would then do the math and decide whether x should be 11,111 or 11,112 shares depending on whether you want the new investor to have slightly more than 10% ownership or slightly less than 10% ownership.  Depending on the investor, your agreement could get quite involved-- the investor could demand a non-dilution clause, for example, so that subsequent rounds of investment doesn't decrease his 10% ownership or the investor could have the right to buy additional shares in the future at the current price or at the future price.

But this is completely up to you and the investor to negotiate.  The investor could buy shares from the existing owners rather than having the company produce new shares.  That puts the investment in the owner's pocket rather than into the business so it's not great for growing the business.  But it may be good if one owner wants to step away partially or completely or wants to limit his or her exposure.

Comment: Since this is for employee purchases, it seems like OP is looking for a consistent *policy* (rather than one-off negotiations) that will treat employees in a uniform way.

Comment: @nanoman - But the scenario he asks about involves an investor buying in.  Wanting to get set up to allow employee options sounds like a future goal.  No employee is going to quibble over whether they're getting 11,111 or 11,112 options or whether that represents just more than 10% or just less than 10% ownership.

Comment: @JustinCave thank you for the answer - very helpful. Yes, I was more puzzled by the technicalities of investors than employee schemes. As you can tell I am very new to this topic (2 days now). The more I dig the more it seems like you just have a big box of lego to build almost any design. I didn't know an investor could request a non-dilutable slice though - that is good to know!